# Simple XML parsing in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch, parsing

I am new to iphone programming and new to parsing xml.

This is my xml:

```
<SpotPrices>
<date>2012-09-14</date>
<gold>1773.90</gold>
<silver>34.77</silver>
<platinum>1714.00</platinum>
</SpotPrices>
```

And this is the method I try to call:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
```

How can pass elements to this method? I am confused because this is the first time I'm trying to do it.